# How to get date of previous year for a certain month and day... and vice versa for current year

Tags: sql-server, date

I was wondering if anyone could assist me with my dilemma, I have a piece of sql where it has to return a certain amount in a current time line, the start date has to be `2014-03-01` and the end date `2015-03-01`. The tricky part now is that it should change every year automatically so I dont have to change it, for example next year is should be `2015-03-01` and `2016-03-01`.

The SQL I have written:

```
 SELECT c.Name AS Biller,SUM(TotalTransactions) AS TotalTransactions, 
  SUM(TotalPay@Fee)/1.14 AS TotalPay@Fee
 FROM tblPay@DailyRetailerBillerTotals d 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPay@company c (nolock) ON d.ClientID = c.RecID 
 WHERE Name = 'Name of Biller'
 AND DateCreated >= 'start date' --2014-03-01
 AND DateCreated <  'end date' -- 2015-03-01
 GROUP BY c.Name
 ORDER BY c.Name Asc
```

Comment: Which SQL version? In 2012 you can use DATEFROMPARTS to create the dates very easily

Comment: How do you determine the month? Is it the current month or does the caller specify it?

Comment: what is your questions ??? i did not get you, can you specify what is expected output

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV the question isn't about output, it's about the search criteria.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so only the year changes right ?? month and date should be constant right ? so he need a query to get the start and end date in each year ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should give you the dates you need:

```
SELECT  YearStart = CAST(CAST(
                            DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - 
                                CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) < 3 
                                    THEN -1 
                                    ELSE 0 
                                END AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0301' AS DATE),
        YearEnd = CAST(CAST(
                            DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - 
                                CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) < 3 
                                    THEN 0 
                                    ELSE 1 
                                END AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0301' AS DATE);
```

The principle is to get a year, then add `'0301'` to it (1st March) to get your date. Then you just need to apply some logic to get the correct year, if the date is January of February, then you need to deduct one from the year to get the previous 1st March.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the previous year to when the query is run.

```
datepart(Year,dateadd(YEAR,-1,GetDate()))
```

This should do what you need.

```
dateadd(YEAR,-1,'2015-03-03')
```

Just replace '2015-03-03' with your date column, and that will give you your start date.

Here's how it looks in your query

```
SELECT c.Name AS Biller,SUM(TotalTransactions) AS TotalTransactions, 
  SUM(TotalPay@Fee)/1.14 AS TotalPay@Fee
 FROM tblPay@DailyRetailerBillerTotals d 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPay@company c (nolock) ON d.ClientID = c.RecID 
 WHERE Name = 'Name of Biller'
 AND  dateadd(YEAR,-1,DateCreated) >= 'start date' --2014-03-01
 AND DateCreated <  'end date' -- 2015-03-01
 GROUP BY c.Name
 ORDER BY c.Name Asc
```

Comment: Applying functions to fields prevents the optimizer from using indexes. It's better (and easier) to apply the functions to the start and end dates

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by apply to the start and end dates rather than columns. Can you explain please I am interested.

Answer (score 0):

it's not that pretty but it should work:

```
  SELECT c.Name AS Biller,SUM(TotalTransactions) AS TotalTransactions, 
  SUM(TotalPay@Fee)/1.14 AS TotalPay@Fee
 FROM tblPay@DailyRetailerBillerTotals d 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPay@company c (nolock) ON d.ClientID = c.RecID 
 WHERE Name = 'Name of Biller'
 AND DateCreated >= CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()-1) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-03-01' AS DATE)
 AND DateCreated <  CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-03-01' AS DATE)
 GROUP BY c.Name
 ORDER BY c.Name Asc
```

EDIT:
datatype `DATE`works only for SQL Server 2008 or later, if you're running a previous version use `DATETIME` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get Start and End Date values in the variable and then use the values in your query:

```
DECLARE @year INT = Datepart(YEAR, getdate())
DECLARE @month INT = 3
DECLARE @day INT = 01
DECLARE @EndDate datetime
DECLARE @StartDate datetime

SELECT @StartDate = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @year - 1 ) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @month) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @day) AS DATETIME)
SELECT @endDate = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @year) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @month) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @day) AS DATETIME)

select @StartDate as [StartDate], @endDate as [EndDate]
```